# Artifactory Docker repo not listening on designated port

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to setup a Docker registry with Artifactory 5.2.1. It's a virtual repo that includes a docker-remote and docker-local (previously defined in Artifactory). I'd like to use the Port method of mapping and I"m running HAProxy 1.5 as a reverse proxy.

HAProxy has a SSL cert with a long list of SANs.

- **artifactrepo.company.com** points to the main artifactory instance and works fine.
- **docker.company.com** points to same server but HAProxy routes this to a Nexus served registry.
- **www.docker.company.com** we intend to route to this Artifactory registry and

Per the HAProxy docs, I've set the `reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /v2(.*$) \1\ /artifactory/api/docker/docker/v2\2` to get me to the intended port and path.

I have the "Registry Port" set to the default 6555 yet there is no process listening on that port. Artifactory and HAProxy have been restarted.

`netstat -tulpn | grep 6555`
gives no results.

Shouldn't Artifactory be listening on the Registry Port?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Turns out it was imagination poisoning from running Nexus repos.

Unlike Nexus, Artifactory doesn't actually listen on any port but the default (8081). The reference to a mapped port for a docker repo is simply to seed the generated reverse-proxy configs they give you. Those configs will have apache listen on 6555 (their default for docker) and then do the path rewrite and port map to 8081. I had intended to do this reverse-proxying using the hostname and had not scrolled all the way through their example to see that they had apache listening on 6555.